# SQL Server data from last 30 days & all data

Tags: sql-server

I want to see all units sold like this

```
select [UnitsSold] from MyTable
```

But I also want to add another column showing only the `UnitsSold` from the last 30 days

How can do this:

```
MyTable.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())
```

but only for one column.

So basically I want to see on the same row all units sold and then units sold the past 30 days

Comment: Can you show us some sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement inside your aggregate function, something like....

```
Select  SUM([UnitsSold]) TotalSold
      , SUM(CASE WHEN CreatedOn >= DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) 
            THEN [UnitsSold] ELSE 0 END) SoldInLastMonth   
FROM MyTable
```